# Merge down columns A and B under each headings

Tags: vba, merge

I am looking to merge a series of headings with a number of blanks underneath such as:

```
Header 1     Header1a
Blank        Blank
Blank        Blank
Blank        Blank
Header 2     Header 2a
Blank        Blank
Blank        Blank
Header3      Header 3a
Blank        Blank
Blank        Blank
```

I have a macro working to merge and center the text, but only works for Column "A".

I'm sure this is a quick fix, but I would like it to run the macro down Columns A and B. Just to clarify, columns A and B to merge individually down the columns and not between each other.

Sub Rectangle1_Click()

```
For i = 6 To Cells(65535, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then Range(Cells(i - 1, 1), Cells(i, 1)).Merge
Next

Range("C5:C2000").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the ,1 in your formulas with ,2 to modify column 2.
Or add another loop running from 1 to 2 to modify both columns in one run.

Does your Sub eliminate all empty cells if you run the loop in this direction?

```
For i = 6 To Cells(65535, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2)) Then Range(Cells(i - 1, 2), Cells(i, 2)).Merge
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that but must have changed something else. Thanks for the response this works fine.

Comment: @FrenchieRab, if this answer solved your question you are invited to mark it as accepted. this both to have other users know this is a working solution of your question and appropriately _reward_ matthias